# How to run django-made venv on pythonanywhere?

Tags: python, django, pythonanywhere

I am a **django beginner** and I have made a django app on my PC that uses **MySQL Connector**. I always run it by going into **django's venv's scripts folder** and then opening a **cmd window and giving an "activate" command.** Then, I go to a web browser and run my website on ***http://localhost:8000***.... I want this **same website run on Pythonanywhere** and **I have uploaded all the files** of django folder **including the venv folder** --- all of them ***correctly placed as in my PC***. When i open a "***bash console***" in the "scripts" folder (placed in venv folder) and type "activate", then it says ***"command not found"***. Please help me. Thank you!

Comment: On pythonanywhere you can select your virtualenv then click "open shell"

Comment: It's worth noting that a virtualenv created on one computer almost certainly won't work on another computer.  You're meant to create a fresh one on each machine, and then use pip to install the packages that you want into it.

Answer (score 1):

For future peoples take a look at this PythonAnywhere help page - https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/Virtualenvs/

Answer (score 0):

click in the three horizontal lines seen in the right side of pythonAnywhere window, click help, django deploy , copy paste below code,

Type `mkvirtualenv –python=/usr/bin/python3.8 venv` //this will create virtual environment, venv

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34532140)

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:

```
workon <venv_name>
```

Comment: the problem is that OP is moving his virtualenv from one machine to another instead of recreating it on the new machine